# How to resolve MySQL error "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"?

Tags: mysql

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`sponge`.`taxonomy`, CONSTRAINT `taxonomy_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organism_id`)  REFERENCES `organism` (`organism_id`))

I am getting this error while deleting entire record.

Actually I wanted to deleted entire record from all table associated by Organism_id in sponge DB.

My Organism Table is:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organism` (
  `organism_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `experts_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `literature_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `genus` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `species` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `scientific_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `organism_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author_org` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `found_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `curated_year` date NOT NULL,
  `curated_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`organism_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=60 ;
```

and Taxonomy table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `taxonomy` (
  `taxonomy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organism_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kingdom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phylum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_tax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `organism_id` (`organism_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;
```

but when i am using delete query:-

```
 SELECT a.*,u.*,s.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.*,i.*,m.*
      FROM organism a
      JOIN taxonomy u
        ON u.organism_id = a.organism_id  
      JOIN synonym s
        ON s.organism_id = u.organism_id_id    
      JOIN biogeography b
        ON b.organism_id = s.organism_id_id 
        JOIN common_name c
        ON c.organism_id = b.organism_id_id 
        JOIN description d
       ON d.organism_id = c.organism_id_id 
     JOIN ecology e
       ON e.organism_id = d.organism_id_id 
     JOIN economic_importance i
       ON i.organism_id = e.organism_id_id 
     JOIN images m

ON m.organism_id = i.organism_id_id 

WHERE m.organism_id = 59
```

I am getting above error...

How can I change my delete query to remove above #1452 error?

Comment: That is not a `DELETE` query, so will not cause that error.

Comment: `(sponge.taxonomy, CONSTRAINT taxonomy_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (organism_id)  REFERENCES organism (organism_id))` means your table 'taxonomy' have a foreign key poiting to the row you are trying to delete. You should first of all delete all rows that are using this FK, then deleting the row from organism table

Comment: actually when i search organism i get searched item in table with edit and delete option.In that case that delete option should delete all records of organism from all table.(eg. taxonomy).pls guid me inorder to do this.

Comment: sorry its not  SELECT while posting i made mistake its DELETE Query actually for delete query i was getting that error..pls guide me for the DELETE Query @Rowland Shaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bob0t said in the comments, the error is caused by the presence of values linked to your `organism_id`, which by default prevents the deletion of the parent row.

You should change the definition of your `taxonomy` table and add the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `taxonomy` (
`taxonomy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`organism_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`kingdom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`phylum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`order_tax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`family` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`taxonomy_id`),
CONSTRAINT org_id FOREIGN KEY (`organism_id`) REFERENCES organism(`organism_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;
```

This way, when you delete the parent row (in table `organism`) you also delete all its referencing children in table `taxonomy`.

## Edit

For completeness of the answer, the delete query should be something as simple as

```
DELETE FROM `organism` WHERE `organism_id` = 59;
```

where `59` comes from your question `WHERE` clause, but it can be any valid ID.